# JdbcTemplate multiple columns

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have an SQL that will return the following result:
[image]

So basically the relationship will be NAME -> MIDDLE -> FAMILY meaning one NAME can have multiple MIDDLE and one MIDDLE can have multiple FAMILY.

I prefer not to create a DAO that will support this table output, ideally I would like to get a Collection of List & Map something like this:  List<String<Map<Map>

How can I fetch the data via JdbcTemplate ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`queryForList`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) might be what you are looking for:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT name, middle, family FROM table");
```

Every `Map` in this `List` represents a row in the returned query, the key represents the column name, and the value is the value of that column for that row.

WRT having unique entries for duplicated rows, you could manipulate the data returned from this to suit what you need. Or, you could use [`query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) that takes a `RowMapper` which will define how each row of your query should be processed.

It's a little hard to understand how you want the data returned because `List<String<Map<Map>` doesn't make sense to me.